# Paypal In Context Checkout: amount not showing

Tags: javascript, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Consider the following two examples which comes from the Paypal developer site, which is https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/

Example 1 (Basic Integration):

```
    plnkr.co/edit/UhNka4VaaRRGY1TK32LE?p=preview
```

Example 2 (Manual or AJAX Integrations):

```
    plnkr.co/edit/UhNka4VaaRRGY1TK32LE?p=preview
```

The payment amount is shown in the first example but not in the second. What is the difference between them that makes this occur? How can I make the 2nd example to show the amount as in the first example?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The amount,item details are to be passed in the setexpresscheckout API call.
Just make sure that you are passing the amount,item details and all other information in the SETEC API.